# SiwftUI Firebase modifying variable inside snapshot change not working

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following is a function to add a listener to a query. Whenever a document is added/removed I make some changes on two arrays (one of the user Ids and one of the user details). As you can see I tried printing everything: I correctly receive the data whenever it is added/removed, I can retrieve the document ID I need but whenever I append it to the usersReqestedUIDs array it always prints it as empty, even if I try to append a random string in it. Why is that?

```
func addRequestedUsersSnapshot() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userRef = db.collection("user").document(user.UID)
    let userRequestedRef = userRef.collection("friends").whereField("status", isEqualTo: "request")

    // First query to fetch all friendIDs
    userRequestedRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: (error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            print("ids : (self.usersReqestedUIDs)")
            print("type : (diff.type)")
            if diff.type == .added {
                print("doc id (diff.document.documentID)")
                self.usersReqestedUIDs.append("hello")
                print("added  (diff.document.data())")
                print("ids : (self.usersReqestedUIDs)")
                self.fetchUserDetailsByUID(uid: diff.document.documentID) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case let .success(user):
                        self.usersReqestedDetails.append(user)
                    case let .failure(error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            if diff.type == .removed {
                print("removed  (diff.document.data())")
                self.usersReqestedDetails.removeAll(where: { $0.UID == diff.document.documentID })
                self.usersReqestedUIDs.removeAll(where: { $0 == diff.document.documentID })
            }
            if diff.type == .modified {
                print("modified  (diff.document.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: I don't know if this is related or will resolve your question, but you don't assign your retrieved documents to any variable. Looking at some of my projects, I see the following pattern: `myCollection.addSnapshotListener { qs, e in guard let s = qs else { return} self.items = s.compactMap { doc in do { let item = try doc.data(as: MyStruct.self) return Item } catch { ... }` Since you never assign anything to a variable, I think it's disappearing.

Comment: So `self.usersReqestedUIDs.append("hello")` doesn't even append to the array, correct? However, `print("doc id (diff.document.documentID)")` does correctly print, correct?